# Problems on the lenght of bond

Tags: chemfig

In the following molecule the lenghth of the bond from `CH_2` is smaller than the other bonds. I tried writing in `CH_{2}`, but it did not work out for me. I am not in the field of chemistry. I will be really happy if someone can guide me to fix that problem.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \setatomsep{1.5em}
 \path node[anchor=south east] (Guanine) {\chemfig{[:180]N(-[:0]@{L2}H)*6(-(=@{L1}O)-(*5(-N=-N(-[:-163]*5(-O-(-[:-252]CH_2-[:-180]O-[:-180]P(=[:-180]O)(-[:+90]O)(-[:-90]O))-@{R6}--))-))=-N=(-N(-[:0]@{L3}H)-[:240]H)-)}} (Guanine.base east) node[anchor=base west, xshift=-.15em] (Cytosin) {\chemfig{[:-30]@{R2}N*6(-(=@{R3}O)-N(-[:-50]{*5(--O-(-[:-70]H_{2}C-[:0]O(-[:0]P(=[:0]O)(-[:90]O)([,,,,red] -[:-90]@{R7}O)))--)})-=-(-N(-[:180]@{R1}H)-[:60]H)=)}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: Everything looks correct. In any case, it's important that you show a complete code and you should check if you have downloaded recent versions of chemfig.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, when I write in in backwords H_{2}C basically everything is ok, but am I changing the structure of the molecule in this case? Is this acceptable?

Comment: @Sebastiano Pentavalent carbon is not something I'd call correct for such structure, plus there are several issues with angular parameters. It probably would help if OP could complete their MWE and attach an illustration of what is expected to be drawn (something as simple as a hand-drawn sketch would suffice).

Comment: Dear Sebastiano. Thank you for your comment (carbon is not something I'd call correct- there are several issues with angular parameters).

Comment: I just added the picture along with the whole coding, hopefully that helps to analyze better.

Comment: I understand very little if I don't see a drawing. I have been enrolled for more than four years and my English has improved a bit, but sometimes I can't understand what the users ask for. I agree with the right comment of @andselisk My regards.

Comment: @andselisk In English I am scarce, in chemistry also....ahahah :-)

Comment: Why did you remove the picture again?

Comment: Dear Cgnieder,there were some other problems as Sabastiano pointed out with angular parameters, therefore i decided to fix those problems first before moving to next stage.